# I want to capture the position of dom update in react to scroll to the position where the dom is updated

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have a very long nested form and after every field there is an error icon which update if any error is occurred anywhere in the form , instead of drilling into the form nodes to find the position of the error I want to capture the position coordinated where the dom update are happening when there is any error that is change in that error icon, so that I can use those positions to scroll to the position

is there any way in react to achieve this functionality to capture coordinates of the dom update

Comment: a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) perhaps?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.